# urllib3 Retry not applying to request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to write a get request with 5 retries, 1 second between each retry:

```
import requests
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

def new_session():
    session = requests.Session()
    retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=1,
                    status_forcelist=[ 500, 502, 503, 504 ])
    session.mount("http://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

    return session

job_url = "http://0.0.0.0:5601/api/reporting/jobs/download/k5rzq3o2000679ee9aeesc27"
session = new_session()

try:
    response = session.get(job_url)
    response.raise_for_status()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I'm expecting the `raise_for_status()` to raise an exception due to the non-200 response code since 5 seconds isn't enough time for the get request to be successful.
Instead the get request takes about 15 seconds and returns a successful 200 code, and retrieves the file correctly.

How come it's not erroring? Why is the request lasting for more than 5 seconds when I've specified `total=5` and `backoff_factor=1`?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you're asking. You've set a retry number (for an error) and there's a timeout (for an error). There is no error. Why would your code retry after a successful connection?

Comment: "due to the non-200 response code" and "... returns a successful 200 code"?

Comment: your request isn't failing so retry do anything here. Also requests do have a parameter called `timeout` - I think this is what you're looking for in case of non-failing requests.

Comment: @roganjosh The request is not meant to return a 200 response code. The only reason it's returning a success is because it's been given enough time to process the request. It works but it shouldn't! 
So I'm trying to figure out why the request is lasting ~15sec instead of 5sec because I need control of this!

Comment: @Charnel I'd rather not use timeout since you need to specify it for each request. I want to specify retries when creating the session

Comment: and what's the difference between specifying timeout per request and per session? Are you suppose to run this requests in parallel?

Comment: @Charnel potentially parallel requests, but it's more that I want to define these properties in one place instead of for each request.
Just for the sake of argument I tried this out, though the timeout doesn't seem to do anything no matter what value I set it to.
So instead of using Retry and the HTTPAdapter, I've just added 
`response = session.get(job_url, timeout=10)`
The request just fails entirely now since there isn't enough time to process. Any ideas why timeout isn't working?

Comment: > The request just fails entirely now since there isn't enough time to process. Any ideas why timeout isn't working? - so requests are now failing because of the timeout. What's exactly not working?

Comment: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts
Ah ok so I've understood timeout properly now - it's not really a substitute for urllib3's Retry. It only applies when the server hasn't returned a response. Whereas my server will return non-200 response codes until the URL is ready.
So `Retry` essentially polls the URL a specified number of times at a specified length of intervals. I'm expecting a number of those 'polls' to return non-200 codes